# Посчитать количество одинаковых строк в data.frame

Tags: r

Имеется data.frame из трёх столбцов и некоторого числа строк

```
vendor <- c("BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "Audi", "Audi", "Mersedes", "BMW", "Audi")
model <- c("X1", "X5", "X1", "A6", "A6", "C-350", "X1", "A6")
year <- c(2009, 2011, 2010, 2015, 2015, 2011, 2010, 2016)

cars <- data.frame(vendor, model, year)

    vendor model year
1      BMW    X1 2009
2      BMW    X5 2011
3      BMW    X1 2010
4     Audi    A6 2015
5     Audi    A6 2015
6 Mersedes C-350 2011
7      BMW    X1 2010
8     Audi    A6 2016
```

Каким образом можно подсчитать число одинаковых строк, в идеале получить новый data frame с четвёртым столбцом, в котором указано число повторений. Что-то типа:

```
    vendor model year count
1      BMW    X1 2009 1
2      BMW    X5 2011 1
3      BMW    X1 2010 2
4     Audi    A6 2015 2
5 Mersedes C-350 2011 1
6     Audi    A6 2016 1
```

Пробовал использовать функцию

```
summary(cars)
```

но она выводит статистику по каждому столбцу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique(cars)
    vendor model year
1      BMW    X1 2009
2      BMW    X5 2011
3      BMW    X1 2010
4     Audi    A6 2015
6 Mersedes C-350 2011
8     Audi    A6 2016`

или с подсчетом количества строк

`library(data.table)
cars <- data.table(cars)
cars[, .N, by = names(cars)]
     vendor model year N
1:      BMW    X1 2009 1
2:      BMW    X5 2011 1
3:      BMW    X1 2010 2
4:     Audi    A6 2015 2
5: Mersedes C-350 2011 1
6:     Audi    A6 2016 1`

Также см. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/identifying-and-removing-duplicate-data-in-r

Comment: Не могли бы, пожалуйста, пояснить, что происходит в этой строке `cars[, .N, by = names(cars)]`? Не до конца понимаю.

Comment: Группировка одновременно по всем столбцам (то есть каждая уникальная комбинация значений становится "группой"), затем подсчет количества строк по группам (.N делает то же самое, что n() в коде с dplyr ниже). По data.table есть не совсем актуальный перевод мануалов https://bookdown.org/statist_/DataTableManual/

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием пакета `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

cars.1 <- group_by(cars, vendor, model, year)
cars.2 <- summarise(cars.1, N = n())

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   vendor, model [?]
  vendor   model  year     N
  <fct>    <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 Audi     A6     2015     2
2 Audi     A6     2016     1
3 BMW      X1     2009     1
4 BMW      X1     2010     2
5 BMW      X5     2011     1
6 Mersedes C-350  2011     1

group_by - группируем заданный набор данных по заданным столбцам
summarise - вычисляем итоги для каждой группы по строкам
n() - количество наблюдений в группе

# вариант записи без промежуточных итогов используюя оператов %>%
cars.3 <- cars %>% group_by(vendor, model, year) %>% summarise(N = n())
```

[Введение в пакет `dplyr` на русском языке](http://rpubs.com/aa989190f363e46d/dplyr_intro)